# Angular material. Dialog actions out of screen on mobile devices

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material2

I have issue with mat-dilog on mobile devices. On mobiles with landscape orientation mat-dialog-actions buttons are outside of the screen, so it is not possible to close dialog.

I thought about dublicating action buttons on top of the dialog with special css class, but it requires manualy add it to every single dialog.

```
// Dialog close button for mobile devices    
.dialog-close-btn {
  visibility: hidden;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 799px) and (orientation: landscape) {
  .dialog-close-btn {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

It works, but like i said it is a lot of repeated code and unnecessary work. Maybe someone faced this problem and have simplier solution. By the way i also noticed that in chrome fullscreen mode there is no this problem, maybe its possible to open dialogs on mobile devices in fullscreen mode? Would be appreciate for any advice).

Comment: Make the dialog smaller.....

Comment: Thought about it, but on devices with diagonal lower than 7" mat-dialog-content block would be too small and it wouldn't be convinient

Comment: It is what it is. It's a mobile device in landscape mode and you're trying to show a dialog with buttons in the footer. We can't tell you how to do the UX design of your app. Angular Material doesn't have any dialog features to handle this screen size specifically. So you'll have to handle this case as you see fit with custom logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some searching and it looks like making the dialog full screen may be a good solution (http://answersicouldntfindanywhereelse.blogspot.com/2018/05/angular-material-full-size-dialog-on.html). I know this takes away from the effect of having a dialog, but I have noticed they can be tricky on mobile if you can't make the content smaller. You might also want to checkout https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10094

Answer (score 2):

The dialog content has a `max-height` style of `65vh` by default (*), which may result in the actions being inaccessibly displayed below the bottom of the screen if the title or actions div is higher than 1 line (as @now noted).

This could be mitigated by applying a custom style to the `.mat-dialog-content` CSS class in a component style file to decrease the maximum amount of height allocated to the content:

```
// In dialog-component.css

.mat-dialog-content {
  max-height: 50vh;
}
```

To apply this in the global style file, use `!important` to force the default style to be overridden:

```
// In global styles.css

.mat-dialog-content {
  max-height: 50vh !important;
}
```

(*) This is based on Angular Material 12.2.6.

Answer (score 1):

Mat dialog expects that the title and actions will fit in a single line. If in your use case the title and/or actions are spanning more lines, you may want to put them all inside content and avoid using mat-dialog-title portion altogether.

```
<div mat-dialog-content class="details">
    <h1 *class="title">{{data.title}}</h1>
    <div> Your content here</div>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did have a same problem.

It's a bit late answer, but I am posting this answer to be helpful to someone who might need this.

 
Based on @Derek Schmid 's answer,

```
  let dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

  dialogConfig = {
    width: '80vw',
    maxHeight: '100vh',
  };
```

Now I am using this config set.

width, minWidht, maxWidht is your choice.

The point is to set 'maxHeight' as '100vh' and do not set 'height' property's value.

This works for me in two points.

1) It's not a full screen so I can still use the value of dialog view(in most cases).
2) In small screen size(in height, like mobile), Both the whole mat-dialog & mat-dialog-content part become scrollable (not just mat-dialog-content part).

Try this out :)